# how to apply function to each checkbox on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to apply a function to every checkbox on a page that shows/hides `<div class="selectlist">` depending on if the checkbox is checked, this function makes all the `<div class="selectlist">` on the page toggle

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").live('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked') == false) {
   $('#selectlist').hide();
    } else {
       $('#selectlist').show();
    }
 });
```

I tried the jquery `each` function like this but that doesnt seem to work

```
    $.each($("input[type=checkbox]").live('change', function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked') == false) {
             $('#selectlist').hide();
        } else {
             $('#selectlist').show();
        }
    }));
```

I know its possible to this by using a `class` instead of `input[type=checkbox]` but I want to avoid doing that

How can I make jquery change the behavior of the checkbox the user clicks?

Comment: Use .on() instead of .live()

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @MelanciaUK doesn't seem to work with .on() could this be due the version of jQuery?

Comment: updated to 1.9.1 version of jQuery and using  .on() instead of .live(), still have the issue of toggling all the <div class="selectlist"> when I check/uncheck a checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to bind an event handler to all elements verifying `input[type=checkbox]`, simply do

```
$(document).on('change', "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
         $('#selectlist').hide();
    } else {
         $('#selectlist').show();
    }
});
```

No need to use `each` there : most jQuery functions work if the jQuery set contains more than one element.

Note that I use `on` there instead of `live` : after having been deprecated for a long time, `live` has been removed from recent versions of jQuery.

---

EDIT : discussion in comments below lead to this code :

```
$(document).on('change', "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
    $(this).next().toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: I updated my question to use classes instead of id, this still toggles all the <div class="selectlist"> on the page

Comment: I don't get what you want. Is it to show/hide only the div following the checkbox ?

Comment: just the div when the checkbox is unchecked

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    $('#selectlist').toggle(this.checked); 
});
```

**ID's are uniqe**, and there is no "all the `<div id="selectlist">` on the page toggle", there can be only one? Use a class instead, and show us what the markup looks like !